# how can I change the header logo to link to an external website in magento?

Tags: magento, hyperlink

I'm trying to achieve the following:

our client needs the header logo of his magento site to take him to another website (different domain).. I have tried to alter header.phtml but the link is becoming: www.websitedomain.com/index.php/www.otherdomain.com

what I want is simply to navigate to www.otherdomain.com

how is that possible?

Comment: change the link in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **http://** like bellow

http://www.otherdomain.com in your anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

You will want to change the link in the image to go to the appropriate location.

I believe the file should be located in:

/app/design/frontend/yourtemplate/yourtemplate/page/html/header.phtml

Comment: i have already tried that, but if i set the link to www.google.com (for example), it becomes www.mywebsite.com/index.php/www.google.com.. (automatically inserts "www.mywebsite.com/index.php" before whatever i type)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes here looking for the answer, in the file named above, at line 105 (v1.9.2) -

Add the url as below

`<h1 class="logo"><strong class="no-display"><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="http://URL.COM" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $logo_src ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>`